# Why did Ocean say, "You don't hear Yen complaining"?

Tags: plot-explanation, oceans-eleven

Inside the vault, Yen placed all the detonators, but got his hand’s
bandage stuck in an inlet. Outside the vault, Ocean and Linus had to
open the vault by using the detonators in order to steal the money
out of it. But the remote’s batteries died:

> Linus: Well, did you check the batteries? You know, you lose focus  in
> this game for one second...
>
> Ocean: I know, somebody gets hurt. **You don't hear Yen complaining**.

Why did Ocean say, "You don't hear Yen complaining"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linus is portrayed as timid and sometimes whiny person throughout the movie. Ocean is simply putting his behaviour in perspective towards the person who is doing the heavy lifting: Yen, who jumps, dives, crawls, carries through lasers, vents and what-not. While the rest of the crew is mostly known for their soft-skills and eloquence.

Also there is a saying which goes a bit like "if you don't do X, somebody gets hurt." Which goes along of the lines of what Linus was saying. Ocean simply completed his sentence with the twist that in this situation somebody DID get hurt. So, it was already too late complain. And if anybody had the right to complain, it would be Yen, who didn't lose focus.

Comment: To that excellent outline I would add the simple practical joke/weak defense that one could not hear Yen complaining even if he did, simply because of the sound barrier provided by the still intact vault door.

Answer (score 2):

Good answer from BestGuess, but I would just add this:

The line is also a bit of a joke because while Yen appears to understand English, he only speaks Mandarin Chinese, which neither Linus or Danny understand. So if Yen was complaining, neither of them would know it.